# Unable to set colors in Highstock charts

Tags: highcharts

Something about my env is interfering with Highcharts. I have simplified the code to:

```
let data = [];
data.push({ name: 'Temperature', data: fake1, color: 'orange', lineColor: 'red' });

    Highcharts.stockChart(divId, {
        navigator: {
            series: {
                color: 'orange',
                fillColor: 'purple',
                lineColor: 'red'
            }
        },

        series: data,
    });
```

The data series is rendered correctly - but with a blue line(s).

The project env is a very complicated DotNet App (not controlled by me) which has Kendo, and plottable and lots of stuff. I have tried commenting out dependencies, no luck.

[image: dev dump]

I can get colors working in a completely standalone env, not in the dot net app. What should I do at this point? I need to control the line colors.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there are two highstock.js files (same name); one that depends on highcharts.css and one that doesn't. Use the one that doesn't.